# Как указать путь для скомпилированных файлов в компиляторе MinGw, C++

Tags: c++, mingw-w64

Простая проблема, как указать относительный путь для исполняемого файла. То есть, в директории в которой находится исходник, находится еще к примеру папка *exe*. Как указать компилятору на то, чтобы он сохранял исполняемые файлы там?

Comment: Указывайте абсолютный путь.

Comment: Казалось бы, все как всегда: `g++ 1.cpp -o my_dir/1.exe`.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! Есть ли возможность, указать в конфигурации компилятора нужную директорию, a в терминале просто ввести `g++ main.cpp` , и файл _a.exe_ сразу сохранится в нужную директорию относительно исходного файла?